# How to embed debezium in a java application to capture Oracle change data?

Tags: oracle, change-data-capture, debezium

I am using debezium in my java application to capture changes from Oracle 12c. The oracle database is accessible on localhost:1521. Below is respective java code.

```
    // Define the configuration for the embedded and Oracle connector ...
    Configuration config = Configuration.create()
            .with("connector.class", "io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector")
            .with("tasks.max", "1")
            .with("offset.storage",
                    "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore")
            .with("offset.storage.file.filename",
                    "/home/username/oracleLogs/offset.dat")
            .with("offset.flush.interval.ms", 10000)
            .with("name", "oracle-debezium-connector")
            .with("database.hostname", "localhost")
            .with("database.port", "1521")
            .with("database.user", "c##xstrm")
            .with("database.password", "xs")
            .with("database.sid", "ORCLCDB")
            .with("database.server.name", "oracle-debezium-server")
            .with("database.out.server.name", "dbzxout")
            .with("database.history",
                    "io.debezium.relational.history.FileDatabaseHistory")
            .with("database.history.file.filename",
                    "/home/username/oracleLogs/dbhistory.dat")
            .with("database.dbname", "ORCLCDB")
            .with("database.pdb.name", "ORCLPDB1")
            .build();

    // Create the engine with this configuration ...
    EmbeddedEngine engine = EmbeddedEngine.create()
            .using(config)
            .notifying(this::handleEvent)
            .build();

    // Run the engine asynchronously ...
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executor.execute(engine);
```

Note that the Oracle database is configured as given [here](https://debezium.io/docs/connectors/oracle/#setting-up-oracle). Also the ojdbc8.jar and xstreams.jar obtained from [Oracle Instant Client](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html) have been imported to the java project.

When the above code is executed, it produces following output even when the Oracle database is shut-down. The changes are not captured either.

```
28 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore  - Starting FileOffsetBackingStore with file /home/username/oracleLogs/offset.dat
```

What am I doing here wrong?

Comment: Did you get the solution for this ? Also, Is it possible to share the sample complete code for this ?. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I didn't get a solution yet. But got some improvements. However [this](https://github.com/chathuranga95/Embedded-Debezium-CDC/blob/master/src/main/java/io/debezium/App.java) is my repo for the code.

Comment: Thank you for response.